# sys.stdout showing something I did not write

Tags: python

I'm doing (Python 3.5):

```
sys.stdout.write('NoNewRecords')
```

it shows me:

```
NoNewRecords12
```

Why is that?

I'm using it to push value for `Apache-Airflow`.
I need to have the exact value as I push.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.write('NoNewRecords')
NoNewRecords12
```

Comment: `write` returns the number of characters it has written, and your interpreter prints the return value of your command. This does not happen when you're executing a script.

Comment: @PeterWood it's a message being pulled by later task. Common use of Airflow scheduler.

Comment: @PeterWood what is different?

Comment: @PeterWood where do you see this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 3, ﻿`write` returns the number of characters it has written, and your interpreter prints the return value of your command. This does not happen when you're executing a script.

Comment: When I execute the script it shows me   VNoNewRecords p0
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369371/how-to-perform-branch-over-tasks-using-airflow-correctly

Comment: @Programmer120 I don't see how that is related to this. You're doing a different thing and getting a different problem.

Comment: how so? if you see something I miss please explain

Comment: In this one, you're calling `write` in an interactive session and getting the character count printed out. In your other question, you're doing something complicated in a script and getting `VNoNewRecords p0`. It is not the same issue.